# Display multiple selections that are selected on change

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having trouble displaying the multiple selections that are chosen in the select box using JS/Jquery. I would like each value to display separated by a comma.

```js
var selectionsInfo;
function setInfo(){
  selectionsInfo = $("option:selected", "#custom-report").val();
document.getElementById("testInfo").innerHTML = selectionsInfo;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="custom-report" name="creport" onchange="setInfo()" multiple="">
      <option value=""></option>
      <option value="10137">bubbles</option>
      <option value="10131">fruit</option>
      <option value="10132">koalas</option>
      <option value="10139">pandas</option>
</select>

<div id="testInfo"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`value` is a plain JS method, not a jQuery one. You need to call `val()` when working with jQuery objects.

In addition, note inline event handlers added using `onclick` should be avoided. You can attach events unobtrusively using jQuery using `on()`. Also note that jQuery 1.12.4 is very outdated. You should upgrade to 3.x.

With all that said, try this:

```js
jQuery($ => {
  $('#custom-report').on('change', e => {
    let values = $(e.target).val();
    $('#testInfo').text(values);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="custom-report" name="creport" multiple="">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="10137">bubbles</option>
  <option value="10131">fruit</option>
  <option value="10132">koalas</option>
  <option value="10139">pandas</option>
</select>

<div id="testInfo"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a jQuery plugin called `$.fn.selectText` that can extract and return an array of selected option text from a `$('<select>')` element.

See the assignment of `textArr` below:

```js
/* #IFNDEF */

/*
 * @filename    select-text.jquery.js
 * @description Include this after jQuery
 * @author      Mr. Polywhirl
 */
(function($) {
  $.fn.selectText = function() {
    return this.find('option:selected').map(function() {
      return $(this).text();
    }).toArray();
  };
})(jQuery);

/* #ENDIF */

function setInfo(select) {
  const
    valueArr = $(select).val() || [],
    textArr = $(select).selectText();

  $("#testInfo").html(valueArr.join(', ') + '<br>' + textArr.join(', '));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="custom-report" name="creport" onchange="setInfo(this)" multiple="">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="10137">bubbles</option>
  <option value="10131">fruit</option>
  <option value="10132">koalas</option>
  <option value="10139">pandas</option>
</select>

<div id="testInfo"></div>
```

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't descriptive. I am having trouble displaying more than one that are selected at the same time. I will edit my post.

Comment: @Jenny Alright, I had a moment, I corrected the example to include a way to grab both the values and the text of a select.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`.val()`](https://api.jquery.com/val/#val1). Here is a working demo with some modifications:

```js
$("#custom-report").on("change", function() {
  $("#testInfo").html( $(this).val().join(", ") );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="custom-report" name="creport" multiple="">
      <option value=""></option>
      <option value="10137">bubbles</option>
      <option value="10131">fruit</option>
      <option value="10132">koalas</option>
      <option value="10139">pandas</option>
</select>

<div id="testInfo"></div>
```